# Postman: set EnvironmentVariable

Tags: postman

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("documentNumRequest", pm.environment.get(documentNumUserPF));
```

Postman noob here. I have this POST call and I want to put the value of "documentNumUserPF" in "documentNumRequest", but i couldn't use the environment variables inside the code. Any tips?

Error:

> ReferenceError: documentNumUserPF is not defined

Comment: ReferenceError: documentNumUserPF is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("documentNumRequest", pm.environment.get("documentNumUserPF"));
```

you are telling to get variable with name documentNumRequest so enclose it with qoutes

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3648

postman keyword will be deprecated in future , so move to new pm api and use it more

```
pm.environment.set("documentNumRequest", pm.environment.get("documentNumUserPF"));
```